# NSOutlineView cell based getting column from the fieldEditor

Tags: cocoa

I've an old project with an outlineView cell based and I want to make an NSAlert if one of the cell has an incorrect value before "outlinView setObjectValue:" get called. I need to know where is located and what I've tried is this w/o success:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{
    if ([control isEqualTo: myOutline]) {
        id item = [myOutline itemAtRow:[myOutline selectedRow]]; // ok
        NSInteger columnNum = [myOutline columnForView:fieldEditor];
        NSLog(@"columnNum = %ld", (long) columnNum); // bad, wrong column, it print 0 but the cell is at column 3
        TreeObj *data = (TreeObj *)[item representedObject];
        // .... rest of the code, return NO if the value is not correct ..

    }
    return YES;
}
```

The "fieldEditor" appear not good to find out the right column because is not the one expected (by me) ..its superview is _NSKeyboardFocusClipView (??). Suggestion appreciated, and feel free to post swift code as well

(EDIT) corrected code accepted from @Willeke:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{
    if ([control isEqualTo: myOutline]) {
        id item = [myOutline itemAtRow:[myOutline selectedRow]]; // ok
        NSTableColumn *tableCoumn = [[myOutline tableColumns] objectAtIndex:[myOutline editedColumn]];
        TreeObj *data = (TreeObj *)[item representedObject];
        if ([tableCoumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"theRightColumn"]) {
            // .... rest of the code, return NO if the value is not correct and display the alert..
        }


    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edited row and column are properties `editedRow` and `editedColumn` of `NSTableView`, the superclass of `NSOutlineView`. The column you're after is `[myOutline editedColumn]` or `myOutline.editedColumn`.

Comment: Wow, so easy... thanks it works!!!!!   Get the right column! Also thanks to be so fast!

Comment: Edited my question by adding the corrected code with your fix!